# Subspace of a consistent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the solution set of a consistent matrix equation $Ax=b$ always a subspace? The answer is false but I do not understand how, if we multiply a matrix with $x$ and get a solution won't we alway arrive at another matrix which passes through $\vec{0}$?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we are given a consistent system $Ax=b$

Suppose $x_1,x_2$ are solution, that is $Ax_1=b$ and $Ax_2=b$ then for solution set to form a subspace we must have $x_1+x_2$ should also be a solution.

But $A(x_1+x_2)=Ax_1+Ax_2=b+b=2b\neq b$

So in general solution set is not a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

We are discussing about the **solution set** of a consistent matrix equation.

Consider the system $$x=1$$

Hence $x=1$ is a solution, but if we multiply it by $2$, it is no longer a solution.